# Vertically center svg with ellipsis

Tags: html, css

I have text that overflows with ellipsis using css. Inside the text is an svg. I can't figure out how to center the svg vertically while still retaining the ellipsis.

Using hacks like `margin-bottom: -0.5rem;` on the svg kind of works but causes other weird visual glitches.

https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-t1gdl0?file=/index.html:0-2965

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Properly overflows</h2>
    <div
      style="overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis;"
    >
      <strong>Warning</strong>
      <svg
        style="
          min-width: 24px;
          max-width: 24px;
          min-height: 24px;
          max-height: 24px;
        "
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white" />
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
          d="M11 13C11 13.5523 11.4477 14 12 14C12.5523 14 13 13.5523 13 13V10C13 9.44772 12.5523 9 12 9C11.4477 9 11 9.44772 11 10V13ZM13 15.9888C13 15.4365 12.5523 14.9888 12 14.9888C11.4477 14.9888 11 15.4365 11 15.9888V16C11 16.5523 11.4477 17 12 17C12.5523 17 13 16.5523 13 16V15.9888ZM9.37735 4.66136C10.5204 2.60393 13.4793 2.60393 14.6223 4.66136L21.2233 16.5431C22.3341 18.5427 20.8882 21 18.6008 21H5.39885C3.11139 21 1.66549 18.5427 2.77637 16.5431L9.37735 4.66136Z"
          fill="#323232"
        />
      </svg>
      At iure maiores aut reprehenderit voluptatem aut recusandae alias qui quam
      quos id corrupti deleniti quo nihil earum. Et quia eligendi sed atque
      provident est exercitationem corrupti. Ut consequatur dolorem aut alias
      earum rem deleniti delectus vel fugit voluptatem.
    </div>
    <h2>Properly aligns vertically</h2>
    <div
      style="
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      "
    >
      <strong>Warning</strong>
      <svg
        style="
          min-width: 24px;
          max-width: 24px;
          min-height: 24px;
          max-height: 24px;
        "
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        fill="none"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      >
        <rect width="24" height="24" fill="white" />
        <path
          fill-rule="evenodd"
          clip-rule="evenodd"
          d="M11 13C11 13.5523 11.4477 14 12 14C12.5523 14 13 13.5523 13 13V10C13 9.44772 12.5523 9 12 9C11.4477 9 11 9.44772 11 10V13ZM13 15.9888C13 15.4365 12.5523 14.9888 12 14.9888C11.4477 14.9888 11 15.4365 11 15.9888V16C11 16.5523 11.4477 17 12 17C12.5523 17 13 16.5523 13 16V15.9888ZM9.37735 4.66136C10.5204 2.60393 13.4793 2.60393 14.6223 4.66136L21.2233 16.5431C22.3341 18.5427 20.8882 21 18.6008 21H5.39885C3.11139 21 1.66549 18.5427 2.77637 16.5431L9.37735 4.66136Z"
          fill="#323232"
        />
      </svg>
      At iure maiores aut reprehenderit voluptatem aut recusandae alias qui quam
      quos id corrupti deleniti quo nihil earum. Et quia eligendi sed atque
      provident est exercitationem corrupti. Ut consequatur dolorem aut alias
      earum rem deleniti delectus vel fugit voluptatem.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For vertically positioning inline-items in text, you can use
`vertical-align: middle;` on the SVG-Element. Make sure to remove the margin. You can try out different values to see what works best, usually 'middle', 'text-bottom' or 'sub'.
Check the available options here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align?retiredLocale=de

Here's your example with vertical-align added:
https://codesandbox.io/s/html-css-forked-05ve1j?file=/index.html